# Hardmode preparation question

Tags: terraria

So I'm preparing for hardmode. I've quarantined my crimson with the usual 4 block wide tunnels. What I'm wondering is should I actually just purify all of it? I've looked at the world in an online mapper and while this would be a big job with just purification powders I'm guessing it would be managable.

I've got a fishing farm and currently am at 80ish wooden, 50ish iron and 14 golden crates with some extra jungle, crimson and corruption crates. And I intend to get more crates before I switch to get a decent chance of being able to make a full set of armor and weapon hopefully without having to break an altar so that I can focus on containing the hallow and crimson that will spawn. I also have a full miners outfit but I'm afraid that will be hard to use with hardmode enemies around.

So in effect does it make sense to purify now or should I just wait for the clentaminator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large sections of Hallow and Corruption/Crimson are spawned when the world enters hard mode, so even completely removing all of the Crimson from your world will not have a lasting effect.

Considering the effort required and the containment work you'll still have to do once the Hallow and Crimson start spreading through stone, it doesn't seem worth it to eradicate the Crimson before hard mode.

Comment: Well, the large stripes from killing the wall can be quarantined and eventually purified too (hellevators and the clentaminator will do the trick). It's the randomly placed specks from breaking altars that can't be easily quarantined due to not knowing where they are.